# Provide array of ids and get rows with repeated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table where I wand to do a query to get same rows multiply times

Races Table:

| id | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fast race | London |
| 2 | cool race | New York |
| 3 | super race | Berlin |

I want to do query where I will search  races in table by id and get results with repeated rows something like this

```
SELECT location FROM races WHERE id = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

And get the following:

```
locations = [
 "London",
 "New York",
 "Berlin",
 "London",
 "London",
 "London",
 "New York",
 "New York",
]
```

Is this possible to do in postgresSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unnest the array then join to it:

```
select r.location
from races r
  join unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]) as t(id) on r.id = t.id;
```

If you want the result sorted by the array position, use `with ordinality:

```
select r.location
from races r
  join unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]) with ordinality as t(id,idx) on r.id = t.id
order by t.idx;
```